# How to get the result of a Linq into a combobox datasource?

Tags: c#, linq, combobox, binding

On my form I have dropped an untyped dataset, and put some tables in it using the designer.

table `SubFolder` with columns `SubFolderID, Category, Folder`
table `ProjectSubFolder` with columns `ProjectID, SubFolderID`

Both table are populated by reading an XML file, and this all works as expected.

Now I need to set the datasource of a ComboBoBox to a list of SubFolders, joined with ProjectSubFolders, and for that I use the following linq

```
DataTable subfolders = dataSetProjects.Tables["SubFolder"];
DataTable projectSubFolders = dataSetProjects.Tables["ProjectSubFolder"];

var query =
    from subFolder in subfolders.AsEnumerable()
    join projectSubFolder in projectSubFolders.AsEnumerable()
    on subFolder.Field<Int32>("SubFolderID") equals projectSubFolder.Field<Int32>("SubFolderID")
    where projectSubFolder.Field<Int32>("ProjectID") == projectID
    && subFolder.Field<string>("Category") == "Models"
    select subFolder;
```

and then I try to set the datasource of the combobox to this

```
comboBoxSubFolderModel.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

The result is that the combobox shows the correct number of rows, but with text `System.Data.DataRow`

So I tried to set the DisplayValue and ValueMember, but that keeps failing.

I tried

```
comboBoxSubFolderModel.DisplayMember = "subFolder.Folder";
comboBoxSubFolderModel.ValueMember = "subFolder.SubFolderID";
```

> EXCEPTION Child list for field subFolder cannot be created

And also DisplayMember remains empty

Next I tried

```
comboBoxSubFolderModel.DisplayMember = "SubFolder.Folder";
comboBoxSubFolderModel.ValueMember = "SubFolder.SubFolderID";
```

> EXCEPTION Child list for field SubFolder cannot be created

And again DisplayMember remains empty

Next attempt

```
comboBoxSubFolderModel.DisplayMember = "Folder";
comboBoxSubFolderModel.ValueMember = "SubFolderID";
```

> EXCEPTION Cannot bind to the new display member; Parameter name:
> newDisplayMember

And again DisplayMember remains empty

So I took a look at the content of the variable `query` to see what is in it,

[image]

[image]

and it appears to me that `query` holds a table called `SubFolder` with the correct fields in it with the correct names.

So, how can I set the displayname and valuemember here ?
Maybe I should not do `query.ToList()` but than what should I use ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure to bind DataRows you need a DataTable for proper binding. There is a CopyToDataTable method that might help you in getting one https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable?view=net-6.0

Comment: @Ralf That works indeed, but is it really necessary to copy the data from my DataTables into a linq and then back again into a DataTable ? It seems such a waist or resources...

Comment: @Ralf If you put this as an answer I will accept it, it does solves my problem

Comment: Then don't use DataTables in the first place?

Comment: @Ralf What do you suggest then in stead of DataTables ? You said yourself I need them to do proper binding

Comment: Binding needs Properties to bind to. DataRows do not have have those. Its a special type with special handling that is tight to DataTables. The alternative is to use normal  classes. Create classes with properties (POCOs)  that represent the xml and use an XmlSerializer for serializing/deserializing.